# How to search for 18 digit salesforce Id using regex? example : you are invited REF<18 digit SFDC ID> for the interview

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

i cannot find answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Ids are 15 or 18 characters of Base 62 data. They consist of the characters `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

So long as your application preserves the case of the Id, the final three characters, which serve as a disambiguator for non-case-safe applications like Excel, can be ignored. Then, you can match `REF<Salesforce Id>` with the regex

```
REF[A-Za-z0-9]{15}
```